# Count consecutive days by product pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need know the number off days each product had sold by row. Exemple "In the day 1 de product AX1 had sold 3, and the product AX2  had sold 2 on the day 1"

I have this:

```
Product | Date       | Sales

AX1     |2019-01-01  | 3
AX1     |2019-01-02  | 2
AX2     |2019-01-01  | 2
AX2     |2019-01-02  | 1
```

But i need this:

```
Product | Date       | Sales | Day

AX1     |2019-01-01  | 3     | 1
AX1     |2019-01-02  | 2     | 2
AX2     |2019-01-01  | 2     | 1
AX2     |2019-01-02  | 1     | 2
```

Comment: Do you need `df['Day'] = df.groupby(['Product']).cumcount() + 1`?

Comment: Yeah, i never heard about ```cumcount()```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

# if not done already:
df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df=df.sort_values(["Product", "Date"])

df["Days"]=df.groupby("Product")["Date"].diff()

mask=df["Days"].isna()

df["Days"]=df["Days"].eq(pd.to_timedelta("1 days"))

df["Days"]=np.where(~df["Days"]&~mask, -df.groupby("Product")["Days"].cumsum(), df["Days"])

df["Days"]=df.groupby("Product")["Days"].cumsum().add(1).astype(int)
```

Outputs:

```py
  Product       Date  Sales  Days
0     AX1 2019-01-01      3     1
1     AX1 2019-01-02      2     2
2     AX2 2019-01-01      2     1
3     AX2 2019-01-02      1     2
```